# Proofs: If-then vs modus ponens

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I am just beginning to study proofs. What is the difference between modus ponens and implies/if-then when relating to proofs?

I figure that we are using modus ponens to advance the proof. If we were using $P \implies Q$, couldn't I start with a false P in order to falsely "prove" Q? In the limited number of proofs I have seen it seems like we just use $P \implies Q$. I am thinking it is either shorthand for modus ponens if we assume what we start out with is true?

How should I understand $\implies$ in proofs?

Comment: You can't do what concerns you because to use modus ponens, you need to establish **both** $P$ **and also** $P \Rightarrow Q$.  That means you won't be able to use a false premise for a bogus proof.  When using $P \Rightarrow Q$ in mathematical writing, in context it's often obvious that $P$ has already been established.

Comment: To clarify, since P is already established. When we say $P \to  Q$ we are using modus ponens just not saying it every time?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Modus ponens, specifically is an *inference rule*. An inference rule is says that a conclusion is true if its premises are true. In other words, the inference rules of a system tell you what manipulations you are allowed to perform that *don't introduce erroneous conclusions*.

Here's modus ponens symbolically.

$$ \frac{A \to B \;\; \text{and} \;\; A}{B} $$

$A \to B$ is a premise. $A$ is a premise as well. $\text{and}$ exists outside the formal language and just tells us that we have both premises. $B$ is the conclusion. The line also exists outside the formal language and tells us how the premises and the conclusion are related.

Modus ponens allows you to take a conditional that you already know and its premise and infer its conclusion. This rule is fundamental to how conditionals are used.

Implies, which I've written $\to$, is how you represent the meaning of *if A, then B*. It is equivalent to the following:

$$ A \to B \;\; \text{is equivalent to} \;\; (\lnot A) \lor B $$

Another way of looking at it is that $A \to B$ is false if and only if $A$ is true and $B$ is false.